# Accessing Rails Session Variable from Backbone View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, backbone.js

This might be a very simple question, but I could not find the answer for it. How should I access a rails session variable from javascript/jQuery (from a Backbone view)? Most likely this is not the best practice, but this is not a problem for me.

Thank you,
Alexandra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon). It allows to send data automatically with each request and let it be accessible from javascript.

For example, after including the gem in your Gemfile, you can add a before filter to your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_filter :set_gon

    ...


    protected
    def set_gon
       gon.my_session_variable = session[:my_session_variable]
    end
end
```

In your application layout, section head of your html:

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

Now you can read this value from your javascript:

```
alert(gon.my_session_variable)
```

This way you only include data specific to the request in your ajax response, and all your extra info is available from the gon variable.

Answer (score 2):

No, session variables reside on the server, so there is no direct method to access the session variable with javascript/jquery.

Your best bet is to make an ajax call with javascript/jQuery to the server to an url you have defined to return the session variable you want in for example JSON format so you can directly access it in Javascript:

```
{
  "sessionVariableName": "sessionVariableValue"
}
```

And no, this is definitely NOT a best practice. Session variables should stay on the server IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this might help someone ...

While ejosafat's answer is valid, the main reason why I needed to access rails session variables from Backbone was to be able to modify them. Since I did not know for sure what I wanted, my question was ambiguous to start with (for example, accessing the session variables did not have to be a direct process). The way I ended up achieving my goal was by using the following four-step process:

1. make sure to initialize the needed rails session variables in the sessions_controller.rb file
2. send the values of the session variables that you want to be able to modify to backbone (in my case, the session variables were accessed by the used rails controller, then sent to the corresponding rails view, and then to the backbone app.js file, which made them accessible to the necessary backbone views)
3. create a function on the rails side (in the used controller) that can update rails session variables based on GET requests from backbone. For example:

   ```
   def modify_session_variables
     if params[:taskParentId]
       session[:task_parent_id] = params[:taskParentId]
     end
   end
   ```
4. each time a backbone variable that represents a session state is changed by the user, send an ajax request to the server with the updated value(s) for the rails session variable. For example, one of my backbone models will update a session variable when one of its attribute is modified:

   ```
   saveAsParentTask: function() {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/modify_session_variables',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          taskParentId: self.getId()
        },
        async: false,
        success: function() {
          App.filtersState.setSubtreeParent(self);
        }
      });
   },
   ```

This process will save the user choices as long as (s)he does not log out of the application. A bit complex, but works the way I want it to.